# Mount an ext4 partition in another PC(Windows) at the same network in my Ubuntu Live?

Tags: ubuntu, windows, ext4, dd, livecd

Is there any way to mount an ext4 partition in another PC, running Windows, at the same network in my Ubuntu Live?

My HD just died earlier today and I needed to use Live Distros until I get a new one. I choose Ubuntu 18.10. I customized my Ubuntu Live and to do it I needed to make an EXT4 partition on my notebook HD(running Windows). I took the HD off and put it in my PC. I want to connect remotely so I won't need to take it off again.

My workaround (no success!): 
I tried mount remotely by windows share a virtual HD image(created with Windows version of DD). This way I got to create the partition and edit my Ubuntu Live '.iso'. The problem was when I tried to copy my edited iso out of the HD virtual image. No matter to where I tried to copy I was getting I/O error at the end of the copy.

I can't set up a virtual machine on my notebook. It has only 2GB of ram.

Comment: **Very clear what OP wants**, but unfeasible.  *Answer posted with a workaround*...

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance!  **:-)** Favour teturned, question upvoted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately¹, Windows cannot even read EXT4 partitions without third-party software. There are a few of them out there that can do local read-only mounting of EXT4 partitions but only one (commercial) that can do both [reads and writes](https://superuser.com/questions/465393/how-to-mount-read-write-an-ext4-partition-on-windows).

However, none of those will allow you to *share* these on a Windows Network: they're for local reading (or writing in one case) only.

So to have full access to your drive remotely you'll have to:

- create an NTFS volume on your USB stick as Linux can easily read and write to NTFS volumes.
- keep data that you want to access remotely on the NTFS volume (Documents, Videos, Music, whatever) as that's just native on Windows and Windows can share it just fine.
- keep the data that you needed to be on the EXT4 where it is now.

<sub>**Note¹:** Actually for us Linux admins that's a *fortunately*  because this way, Windows cannot mess up EXT4 partitions...</sub>